# md-slider changing only the first dot

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-material

i'm trying to play with the size and color of the first dot in the md-slider, i looked around but only find a way do display:none the dots, there is nothing about the height and/or color and absolutely nothing about working on a specific dot. i will probably just add an outside element but this is a work around that i'm not 100% comfortable with.

```
 <md-slider ng-show="firstCondition === false" 
       ng-disabled="true" flex="" 
       style="margin-right: 2%;" 
       class="md-primary " md-discrete 
       ng-model="mySlider[0]"   
       step="1" min="0" max="3" aria-label="mySlider">
  </md-slider>
```

css:

```
 .md-track-ticks canvas { 
    display: none; 
}
 .md-track-ticks canvas:first-child { 
    display: inline-block; 
    background-color:orange;
    width:12px;height:12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this Is the work around i used (until a better solution will present himself)

```
<ng-md-icon icon="lens" size="12" style=" fill:#111;position:absolute;top: 23px;left:1px;"></ng-md-icon>
```